# Youtube video URL extractor

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that returns the ID of a youtube video's URL in a string format. I thought I recognized the pattern as always being the last 11 characters of a video's URL. However when running my function against several tests it failed more than it worked! I am curious how I could achieve the intended result given so many variations. Here is my code:

```
function youtubeId(link) {
 const linkArr = link.split("");
 return linkArr.slice(linkArr.length - 11).join("");
}
```

Here are the tests it has to pass, with the expected output:

```
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPEr1cArWRg"), "XPEr1cArWRg")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SNQGyVW_YI&t=8871"), "-SNQGyVW_YI")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("https://youtube.com/watch?t=4m40s&v=vxP3bY-XxY4"), "vxP3bY-XxY4")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL3QZUm48uWnsdFakp3A2fI-NzmfH1jyQe&v=yv56ncTdTmU&index=8"), "yv56ncTdTmU")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("https://youtu.be/BCDEDi5gDPo"), "BCDEDi5gDPo")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=jOxnoDi9IYg&t=3311s"), "jOxnoDi9IYg")
Test.assertEquals(youtubeId("https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2w9SQjdn9U4"), "2w9SQjdn9U4")
```

Comment: just look for ```v=``` in the URL and take the next 11 characters. There is no guarantee it will be at the end

Comment: Or use the `URL` class to parse the URL, get its search parameter.

Comment: Looks like there are only 3 variants, `v=`, `embed/` and `youtu.be/` the next 11 chars is the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pattern `[/=]([\w_-]{11})\b`

- `[/=]` Look for a slash or equals denoting the pattern will follow
- `([\w_-]{11})` Capture an 11 character string made up of letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes

```js
var inputs = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPEr1_ArWRg",
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SNQGyVW_YI&t=8871",
"https://youtube.com/watch?t=4m40s&v=vxP3bY-XxY4",
"www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL3QZUm48uWnsdFakp3A2fI-NzmfH1jyQe&v=yv56ncTdTmU&index=8",
"https://youtu.be/BCDEDi5gDPo",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=jOxnoDi9IYg&t=3311s",
"https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2w9SQjdn9U4"]

function getID(str){
  const id = /[/=]([\w_-]{11})\b/.exec(str)[1]
  
  console.log(id)
}

inputs.forEach(getID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better solution to actually parse the URL as you won't have to rely on the ID being exactly 11 characters long and it won't fail on unexpected characters either:

```js
function parseURL(url) {
 var parser = document.createElement('a'),
  searchObject = {},
  queries, split, i;

 // Let the browser do the work
 parser.href = url;

 // Convert query string to object
 queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
 for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
  split = queries[i].split('=');
  searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
 }

 // Return object with url data
 return {
  protocol: parser.protocol,
  host: parser.host,
  hostname: parser.hostname,
  port: parser.port,
  pathname: parser.pathname,
  search: parser.search,
  searchObject: searchObject,
  hash: parser.hash
 };
}

function youtubeId(url){
 var urlObj = parseURL(url);
 var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(urlObj.search);
 var id = searchParams.get('v');

 // Check if the url had a 'v' parameter
 if(id !== null){
  console.log(id);

 // No parameter found, id must be in path
 } else {
  var paths = urlObj.pathname.split('/');
  console.log(paths[paths.length - 1]);
 }
}

var urls = [
 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPEr1_ArWRg',
 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SNQGyVW_YI&t=8871',
 'https://youtube.com/watch?t=4m40s&v=vxP3bY-XxY4',
 'www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL3QZUm48uWnsdFakp3A2fI-NzmfH1jyQe&v=yv56ncTdTmU&index=8',
 'https://youtu.be/BCDEDi5gDPo',
 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=jOxnoDi9IYg&t=3311s',
 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/2w9SQjdn9U4'
];

urls.forEach(youtubeId);
```